# std::filesystem sees deleted files

Tags: c++, windows, std-filesystem

Why std::filesystem sees deleted files?

```
for (auto& file : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(game_folder))
{
     cout << file.path().string().c_str() << endl;
}
```

this code shows me the files deleted (by me)

Comment: platform? Windows, Mac, linux?

Comment: Chances are, the files are actually open, and will not be fully deleted by the OS until all open handles to them have been closed.

Comment: @pm100 Windows x64

Comment: Are you deleting them while iterating over the directory?

Comment: @drescherjm before

Comment: [`DeleteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-deletefile) explains how file deletion works: *"The `DeleteFile` function marks a file for deletion on close. Therefore, the file deletion does not occur until the last handle to the file is closed."*